# "Field Limit is too big for your chosen Column Type" error on already existing fields when updating matrix

Tags: craft3, matrix, field, error, fieldtypes

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to update a matrix:

"Field Limit is too big for your chosen Column Type.""

I'm trying to add a new block type but this error keeps getting up on fields that already exist in other block types. 
The problem seems to related to the plain text field type. I've read somewhere about the field limit exceeding the mysql varchar length but 80 or 100 shouldn't be a problem, no?

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

I'm running on:

- PHP version 7.2.15
- OS version  Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit
- Database driver & version   MySQL 5.7.26
- Image driver & version  Imagick 3.4.3 (ImageMagick 6.9.7-4)
- Craft edition & version Craft Pro 3.4.19
- Yii version 2.0.35
- Twig version 2.12.5
- Guzzle version  6.5.3
- Imagine version 1.2.3-dev

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down a little bit from your screenshot, you'll see an "advanced" toggle for the Plain Text field settings.

In there is a "Column Type", which I'm guessing is set to `varchar(255B)` for you.

Set that to `Text` and that should solve it for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue but I'm a bit confused as why this suddenly is a problem.